# Java add border to a label changes the label size when mouse click happens

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, border

I am working on adding a border indicates mouse click event. I had two image in two separate labels using flow layout. I have implement a mouse click event on each selection I had.

When I click on label 1, blue border is created and label 2 border (if the other label is selected) becomes an empty border. The same happens in the other way around.

```
label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(label2Selected == true){
            label2Selected = false;
            label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            label2.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }
        label1Selected = true;
        LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 5, true);
        label1.setBorder(border);
        label1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
    }
});
```

The issue is when one of the label is clicked, the image (label) position shift horizontally and vertically (noticeable when clicked). Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After a lunch break, I thought of a solution that works well now,

```
EmptyBorder emptyBorder = new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
label1.setBorder(emptyBoder);

label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(label2Selected == true){
            label2Selected = false;
            label2.setBorder(emptyBorder);
            label2.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }
        label1Selected = true;
        LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 5, true);
        label1.setBorder(border);
        label1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
    }
});
```

So, the workaround is to create an empty border on label first with the size of the colored border.